# excel macro range using cells error

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set a range in the code below, first i define the last column, it is success, I got the column "9" = column I

and I want to use the `lastcol2` variable into my range like below code:

```
Set check2 = Sheets("filterx")
lastcol2 = check2.Cells(1, check2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range("A1:AI" & lastrow1).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("filterx").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, lastcol2)), _
    CopyToRange:=Range("BA1:CI1"), Unique:=False
```

however, it doesnt work on the code. what is wrong with my code? 
`Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, lastcol2))` is the wrong part.

If I replace it into `Range("A1:I2")` it works perfectly. please tell me the reason.

Comment: what is the actual value of `lastcol2`?

Comment: Can the CriteriaRange be more than one cell? Trying to run your code for myself I get a complaint regarding that, but I don't have any data in my sheet so I suppose it could be something related to that as well. Apart from that, I'd advice to fully qualify the all ranges you refer to, and use the variable you've defined for the worksheet instead of keeping on hardcoding it's name. I.e. do something like `check2.Range(check2.Cells(1, 1), check2.Cells(2, lastcol2))`

Comment: Additionally, including the exact error message you get would be helpful in pinpointing the problem.

Comment: @eirikdaude you are correct. I use your code and it works perfectly